# Capture numbers inside square brackets

Tags: python, regex

I want to capture all the numbers which are inside square brackets. The numbers are separated by commas. For an example I want to capture 7, 8 and 5 from the text `some text [7, 8], some other texts with 1 or 2 numbers [5]. other texts.`

I tried to use the following pattern

```
pat = (?<=\[)[\d,\s]*(\d)[\d,\s]*(?=\])
```

But it seems that for the case "[7, 8]" the patterns are overlapping and I am only getting "8".

Comment: Use a common workaround, `re.findall(r'\d+(?=[^][]*])', text)`

Comment: Why do you have non-capturing groups? It would seem you're missing out e.g., the `(?:\d,\s)` group, which contains the first digit (when there are more following the comma), just like in your results.

Comment: @0 0 I edited the pattern. Still it's not working

Comment: @Wiktor yes, I am currently trying that, but more specific solution would be helpful.

Comment: What do you mean by a "more specific"?

Comment: I want a solution, where the restrictions will be more clearly defined. Numbers inside square brackets separated by commas. Also for some reason your solution is not working

Comment: Ok, why not use two steps? Like `result = [re.findall(r'\d+', x) for x in re.findall(r'\[(\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*)]', text)]`? See [this demo](https://ideone.com/yoZoZQ). Or, `[list(map(str.strip, x.split(','))) for x in re.findall(r'\[(\d+(?:,\s*\d+)*)]', text)]` ([demo](https://ideone.com/qF0Bel))

Comment: @Wiktor I actually ended up solving the problem in two steps using the patterns in Mats answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a lookbehind and lookahead is, IMHO, going overboard with using regular expressions. You are probably better of capturing the entire pattern and then chopping off the first and last bracket. Something like this is easier to follow and understand:

```
import re

sample = r"""
some text [7,8], some other [2, 3] texts with 1 or 2 numbers [5]. [4,
5] other texts
"""

result = [ s[1:-1] for s in re.findall(r'\[\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+)*\]', sample) ]
print(result)
```

If you really want to use a regular expression to capture the result, this works:

```
result = re.findall(r'\[(\d+\s*(?:,\s*\d+)*)\]', sample)
print(result)
```

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew You're so right. I just assume everything returns a generator. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

With [PyPi regex](https://pypi.org/project/regex/):

```py
import regex
pat = r'\[(?P<numbers>\d+)(?:,\s*(?P<numbers>\d+))*]'
s = r'some text [7, 8], some other texts with 1 or 2 numbers [5]. other texts.'
results = [match.captures('numbers') for match in regex.finditer(pat, s)]
print(results)
```

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##XY9BDoIwEEX3nGJ2bZGQqDEao3IF96ULhCJNpG2mQ8TTV0QWxu2b@W/m@xd1zm5jNL13SID6rsfEVwRnQFZKXlxPduhvGsOlbFaCF8esDOk/FqliSZgzwfUaSI8Ecp/BQWUwE0edxpkHeBrqYA0OYQOLBeRO5b9LOUtQh@FBH6vsK6q7vK48DRPlbEkxAe1kmadg7Pf7vDW2MaSRTzWm60IlHo0lvvhEjG8).

**Results**: `[['7', '8'], ['5']]`.

**EXPRESSION EXPLANATION**

```py
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  \[                       '['
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?P<numbers>               group and capture to "numbers":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times (matching
                             the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )                        end of \k<numbers>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  (?:                      group, but do not capture (0 or more times
                           (matching the most amount possible)):
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    ,                        ','
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    \s*                      whitespace (\n, \r, \t, \f, and " ") (0
                             or more times (matching the most amount
                             possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (?P<numbers>               group and capture to "numbers":
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
      \d+                      digits (0-9) (1 or more times
                               (matching the most amount possible))
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    )                        end of \k<numbers>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  )*                       end of grouping
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  ]                        ']'
```